# Table with predefined dimensions and horizontally and vertically centered cells

Tags: tables, dimensions, vertical, horizontal

I have a hard time making a table that would have predefined dimensions (the whole page) and cells centered horizontally and vertically.  I have found solutions for each of those problems individually,but they does not work together. Solutions that I have found so far took me to this point:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[total={17cm,25.7cm}, top=2cm, left=2cm, includefoot, bindingoffset=-0.63cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[twoside, hscale=0.88, vscale=0.88, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,adjustbox}


\newcommand{\finalcells}[2]{%
  \begingroup\sbox0{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\raggedright#1\end{minipage}}%
  \sbox2{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\raggedright#2\end{minipage}}%
  \xdef\finalheight{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0+\smallskipamount\relax}%
  \xdef\finalheightB{\the\dimexpr\ht2+\dp2+\smallskipamount\relax}%
  \ifdim\finalheightB>\finalheight
    \global\let\finalheight\finalheightB
  \fi\endgroup
  \begin{minipage}[t][\finalheight][t]{3cm}\raggedright#1\end{minipage}&
  \begin{minipage}[t][\finalheight][t]{3cm}\raggedright#2\end{minipage}}


\begin{document}

{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3.5 cm}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.25cm}

\begin{tabular}{| m{8.5cm} | m{8.5cm} |} 

\hline
asdasd  & • \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
• & • \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
}


\end{document}
```

It creates the table witch predefined dimensions, but the text is not centered.
The thing that I actually want is to make two-sided (playing) cards that would match after the printing.
Thank for any advice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See if use of `\begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8.5cm} 
                | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8.5cm} |}` gives what you like to have. BTW, why you define table cells on so complicated way?

Comment: @user227450  please have a look at the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you like to have. More empty space above/below cell contents? What should happen, if you have longer text in cells, for example if it is break in four lines?

I guess, that the following (much simpler) solution gives what you like to get:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[total={17cm,25.7cm},
            top=2cm, left=2cm,
            includefoot, bindingoffset=-0.63cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace} % for additiona vertical space above/below cells contets
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{22pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{22pt}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\centering\arraybackslash}O{m{8.5cm}} 
                    | >{\centering\arraybackslash}O{m{8.5cm}} |}
    \hline
asdasd      & \lipsum[1][1-3]   \\
    \hline
    •       & •                 \\
    \hline
    •       & •                 \\
    \hline
    •       & •                 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your friend in such cases is the command

```
\rule[-5em]{0pt}{10em}
```

which adds an invisible rule above and below the contents of each cell  -- dimensions as per choice

The pros an cons of various types of vertical and horizontal padding are discussed at many places on this site including   --

[Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables)

The new `P` type of column gives the horizontal and vertical centering which you look for
-- with `\centering` for horizontal centering and `m{}` giving the vertical centering in the command

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\rule[-5em]{0pt}{10em}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
```

The width of each column is defined as a percentage of the text width by simply entering `P{0.4}` thereby meaning the column will take up 40% of the text width

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage[total={17cm,25.7cm}, top=2cm, left=2cm, includefoot, bindingoffset=-0.63cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[twoside, hscale=0.88, vscale=0.88, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,adjustbox}

%
%\newcommand{\finalcells}[2]{%
%   \begingroup\sbox0{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering#1\end{minipage}}%
%   \sbox2{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\centering#2\end{minipage}}%
%   \xdef\finalheight{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0+\smallskipamount\relax}%
%   \xdef\finalheightB{\the\dimexpr\ht2+\dp2+\smallskipamount\relax}%
%   \ifdim\finalheightB>\finalheight
%   \global\let\finalheight\finalheightB
%   \fi\endgroup
%   \begin{minipage}[t][\finalheight][t]{3cm}\centering#1\end{minipage}&
%   \begin{minipage}[t][\finalheight][t]{3cm}\centering#2\end{minipage}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\rule[-5em]{0pt}{10em}\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
\begin{document}
    
%   {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3.5 cm}
        %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.25cm}
        
        \begin{tabular}{| P{0.4} | P{0.4} |} 
            
            \hline
            asdasd  & • \\ 
            \hline 
            • & • \\ 
            \hline 
            • & • \\ 
            \hline 
            • & • \\ 
            \hline 
            • & • \\ 
            \hline 
            • & • \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
%   }
    
    
\end{document}
```